# PhoneGap Memory Management

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, cordova

For few months now I have been developing an Android app using `PhoneGap 2.8` and on the javascript side I have used `Backbone` and `jQuery` as my main frameworks. As my application has grown to a reasonable size, I have started to notice a considerable memory consumption. Having read different articles that explain why `PhoneGap` requires considerable amount of memory even to run, I still believe that I can do some optimization to how i use memory.

In `BackBone` we have a Router object that maps URI-s to specific functions, which render me something called a `View` object. Not only I implemented my router functions to create a view and render it, but I also store globally reference to currently being displayed view. So before a new view is created, I tell the old view to make some clean up (That is done recursively since views can contain more "sub" views). Under clean up I currently tell view to undelegate his events (I trust `Backbone` removes the event listeners). Not much more is done currently. Once new view is rendered, global variable will reference the new view. I trust that javascript GC will release the memory, used by the old view. Alas, I dont things this is happening- the more I navigate around my app, the more memory is being used up. I am aware that there is some memory leaking going on, but I can't figure out what is it, that takes memory. One thing I suspect is that old objects are not being garbage collected properly for some reason. I suspect that once I render new html (DOM) over some container, perhaps old `DOM` is causing memory leaks, perhaps some event handlers are being unnecessarily stored somewhere.

What I would like to know, if there is any tools or commands or tips on how can I debug/ trace/ measure where memory is being allocated. Is there a way to access all event listeners and measure them somehow (same for DOM). Any article to smart memory efficient techniques would also be appreciated. Currently only thing that I can thing of to do, is to start recursively deleting all attributes of the objects (in the end objects as well) I am willing to destroy.

Any suggestion is very welcome! 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since I use jQuery to add content to DOM via .html(data) function, I have read that calling .empty().html(data) is a better choice, since empty() removes the event handlers and all texts before removing DOM elements. Having read  that, I have prepended empty() to all my .html() calls, and I havent noticed considerable improvement. I still believe that the root of the problem is to be found.

Comment: Chrome has an extension to use with ADB but I think it only works with Chrome not native Android browser (which being used in WebView) https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging. Paul Irish had suggested a list of tools you may able to use: https://plus.google.com/+PaulIrish/posts/ccP98BTMd5Z. I have used [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) before but it doesn't do profiling. [jsHybugger](http://www.jshybugger.org/) may able to help you.

Comment: I have tried jsHybugger and I really like the feature it currently provides. Developer of jsHybugger informed me that soon he will release a version that will include Timeline tab functionality as well as seeing the current javascript objects in the memory (exactly what I need). In other words, jsHybugger is a really really useful tool for phonegap development and I recommend it to everyone.

Comment: Is there a difference between jsHybugger and Remote Debugging Chrome on Android?
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issues with my first phonegap app. Few techniques we managed to apply were

*old view - view getting navigated away

- Unbind all events associated with old view
- Remove all nodes attached to the view from dom, to make sure event are also removed
- Remove old view object, model/collection, so that there are no instances remaining on the DOM
- Moreover try to use prototyping as much as possible, as functions created via prototype occupy space in RAM only once. So if the view is created/initiated again, its associated/child functions aren't going to be pushed into RAM again
- Most imp, make sure 'this' pointer isn't leaking anywhere between files. One of my workplace used to get stuck after 1.5 hrs of play and after a week debugging, we came to find out that there was a leakage of this pointed between 2 files/objects/views, which created a circular referencing and make the DOM to explode.

Also you can try to use Google Chrome's profiling tool

Few useful links

- http://blog.socialcast.com/javascript-memory-management/
- [Backbone.js Memory Management, Rising DOM Node Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126334/backbone-js-memory-management-rising-dom-node-count)